# Backspace and UTF8 encoding in terminal

Tags: php, utf-8, terminal

Here is a simple PHP test script:

```
// Get a string from terminal
echo "> ";
$string = trim(stream_get_line(STDIN, 999999, PHP_EOL));

// string to hex:
$hex='';
for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
{
    $hex .= dechex(ord($string[$i]));
}

echo "$string $hex\n";
```

Fist launch, i type "Привет":

```
gkuzovnikov@gkdevel:~$ php ~/test.php
> Привет
Привет d09fd180d0b8d0b2d0b5d182
```

Next launch, i type "Привет" **then press backspace**, and press "т" again:

```
gkuzovnikov@gkdevel:~$ php ~/test.php
> Привет
Приве�т d09fd180d0b8d0b2d0b5d1d182
```

It seems that when I press backspace only one byte from input sequence is removed, while all the characters are two bytes length.

Is there a way to get a string from input, so the user can correct it during typing?

Comment: Have you tried the standard html input ?

Comment: @RohitGupta I need to get a string in my console php script. Html input is for web pages. Or what do you mean?

Comment: I am confused, are you trying to write a desktop application using php ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to that is to check whether the `stty` *extension* [`iutf8`](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2012/08/msg01132.html) is supported in your configuration and whether it is in effect at the point where you are seeing the problem.

Conventionally, terminal drivers remove a single *byte* from the input on receipt of an erase character.  However, UTF-8 is a multibyte encoding (multiple bytes per character), and user's expectations are better met by

- removing all of the bytes for the last input *character* (by the terminal driver) and
- moving the cursor left (by the terminal emulator).

The `stty` extension was added initially as a Linux kernel patch (see [2004 mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2004-04/msg00021.html) discussion), and appears to be supported in some other systems (OSX for instance).  This `stty` command was run in `xterm` on OSX 10.9, and shows `iutf8` as an option in the `iflags` section:

```
bash-3.2$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; 24 rows; 80 columns;
lflags: icanon isig iexten echo echoe echok echoke -echonl echoctl
        -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho pendin -nokerninfo
        -extproc
iflags: -istrip icrnl -inlcr -igncr ixon -ixoff -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
        -ignbrk -brkint -inpck -ignpar -parmrk
oflags: opost onlcr oxtabs onocr onlret
cflags: cread cs8 parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts -dsrflow
        -dtrflow -mdmbuf
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = ^@;
        erase = ^H; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V; min = 1; quit = ^\;
        reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z;
        time = 0; werase = ^W;
```

The `erase` setting is of course, the "backspace" key.

Comment: You are right, it is the problem of my terminal app. It present in Gnome terminal, while in XTerm everything is ok. In both terminals erase character is ^? I tried to set ^H (as is in yours settings) but it doesn't work. Do you have any ideas how to repair my Gnome terminal? (I use ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: Not offhand - I have seen occasional bug reports for the feature.

Comment: If anybody else faced that too, I had the same issue due to running a binary that reads the input from inside a development docker container. And **the fix was to run the binary directly from Ubuntu's terminal**. Note: interestingly, when I run `stty -a` from the docker container I had the `iutf8` flag reported.